# Bootstrap 4 Card Collapse Height Incorrect in IE11

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

Hi this is my first question here and my web development experience is beginner level so please go easy on me thanks.
I've been spending ages trying to figure out how to get an 'accordion' style vertical menu to work in IE11, it works in Chrome and IE10, I've not tested any other browsers yet.
I've stripped my code back to this fiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/martin46/gygzd52t/1/

It seems IE11 first gets the height right then after a second adds additional space to the bottom of the expanded menu, this has a 'jerky' effect and the space looks unsightly.
Although it is possible to get this working by removing the list and label elements and adding line breaks I need a solution that keeps the labels that wrap the input elements.
Many thanks.

The code in the fiddle is;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">       
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#List1">
                    List 1
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="List1" class="collapse">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <ul style="margin:0;">
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />A</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />B</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />C</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />D</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />E</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />F</label></li>
                        <li><label class="card-text"><input type="checkbox" />G</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side-note: You should only include one version of jQuery. If you don't need AJAX (do web requests in your code), you can keep the "slim"-version.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code and removed the additional / unnecessary jquery script reference, unfortunately it hasn't resolved the problem though.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing same problem.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and this answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057416